# How to understand global and local variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

1st test:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a);    // 1
```

2nd test:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
}
b();
alert(a);    // 10
```

In the first test, `a` is equal to `1`, although I set it to `10` in the method. In the second test, I set it to `10` and it is set to `10` when I output it.. How does this work?

Comment: This example and its explanation are provided here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function declaration `function a() {}` declares a variable name `a` in the local scope of your `b` function (and assigns it the function). When you are assigning to `a`, you will assign to that local variable not the global one.

With hoisting applied, your code is equivalent to

```
var b = function b() {
    var a = function a() {};
    a = 10;
    return;
}
var a = 1;
b();
alert(a);    // 1, obvious now
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the hoisting creates a local variable `a` that masks the global one before you try to assign a value to it.

Comment: I see. Quite tricky. Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

In your first test, you create a function which is stored in the **local** variable `a`:

```
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {} // can be called using a() inside this function
}
```

So you could call this function using `a()` inside your function `b()`. Try:

```
function b() { 
    a(); // alerts "hi"
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() { alert("hi"); }
}
```

Now, you store in the local variable a the number 10 instead of the function. The global variable remains unchanged, therefore your outer alert still shows 1.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is interpreted (by JavaScript) as:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
  var a = function () {};
  a = 10;
  return;
}
```

In JavaScript, all local variables (in this case the local variable a that will hold the function) are declared at the top of the function.

The local variable a gets set to 10 rather than the global. It then ceases to exists after return.